# Nodejs Expess Script Unable to Create the Mysql Database Table

Tags: mysql, node.js

I created  node js express applications with express generator. I am trying to create table by executing database script called db.js . This script is located into database folder . I am able to run the server but when I tried to execute the script by using  **C:\Users\Khundokar Nirjor\Desktop\Nodejs Resources\shopping-cart\database>node db.js
C:\Users\Khundokar Nirjor\Desktop\Nodejs Resources\shopping-cart\database**>

It is not able to create the table or inserting records.

Here is my app.js code .

```
 var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
var expressHbs = require('express-handlebars');
var mysql = require('./database/db');
var app = express();

require('./database/db');
// view engine setup
app.engine('.hbs',expressHbs({defaultLayout: 'layout' , extname: '.hbs'}));
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
//app.use('/users', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Here is the db.js code .

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
//var app = express();

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database: "shopdb"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
  var sql = "CREATE TABLE products (imagepath VARCHAR(255), tittle VARCHAR(255), descriptions VARCHAR(255),price VARCHAR(255))";
  var sql1 = "INSERT INTO products (imagepath, tittle,descriptions,price) VALUES ?";
  var values = [
    ['https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/5e/Gothiccover.png', 'Gothic Veido Game','Awesome Game !!!!','25'],
    ['https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/5e/Gothiccover.png', 'Gothic Veido Game','Awesome Game old !!!!','100'],

    ['https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/5e/Gothiccover.png', 'Gothic Veido Game','Awesome Game New !!!!','120'],
    ['https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/5e/Gothiccover.png', 'Gothic Veido Game','Awesome Game !!!!','26'],

  ];
  con.query(sql, sql1,[values], function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Number of records inserted: " + result.affectedRows);
  });

});
con.destroy();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should enable multistatement true while creating a connection as you are running multiple statements.change your configuration options as below:

```
var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database: "shopdb",
  multipleStatements: true
});
```

Refer this :
https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#multiple-statement-queries